# Keeping the first row format after selecting other active cells

Tags: excel, vba, format

Currently, the code always select column "A" of the active row when selecting any active cell excluding Row 1, and rename that Column A cell "My Range" Temporarily. That's what the first few lines achieve, afterwards I am trying to Highlight any active row after Row 2, and clear the highlight when another active row is selected.

There seems to be an issue when selecting another active row, as the previous row is not clearing the coloring.

So in the example, I have selected Test 1 (Row 3 is the Active Row):

[image]

When Selecting another Active Row, such as Test 2 (Row 4 is now the Active Row), the Active row is colored but the previously colored row 3 is still colored in

[image]

Anytime I select another active row, the previous row is not clearing its coloring and I want to maintain any coloring in Row 1 (the black fill in column I1), this is what I want the output to look like when I select another Active Row, so in this case I Test 1 was the active Row (Row 3), but when I selected Test 2 (Row 4) as the active Row, Row 3 clears it's coloring like so:

[image]

Here is the entire code that I am running:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False                                                          'This speeds up the macro by hiding what the macro is doing

        If Target.Row > 1 Then

        ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="MyRange", RefersToR1C1:=Range("A" & (ActiveCell.Row))   'Defines the name of the ActiveCell as "MyRange" to Autofill VLookup Formula on sheet

        Range("A" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Select                                                    'Always Selects Column A depending on the Active Row selecte

        Dim TR As Variant

        TR = Target.Row > 2

        With TR                                                                                 'With Target refers to the Active Row being selected greater than Row 2

        Target.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 0                                                'Clears Previous Cells Interior Color

        Target.EntireRow.Interior.Color = RGB(243, 243, 123)                                    'Highlights the entire row that contain the active cell

        End With

        If Target.Address = "$A$2" Then                                                         'Checks if you have selected Row 2 (The comparison row)

            Target.Value = ""                                                                   'If Cell A2 is selected (the "Key" comparison cell from the comparison row) then a blank value is inputted

        Else

            [a2] = ActiveCell                                                                   'Makes cell "A2" equal to the Active Cell value (The "Key" in this case)

        End If

    End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True                                                           'Must be "True" after running the code to be able to Read/Write the Workbook

End Sub
```

Comment: `Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 0` is every cell on the sheet. And the preceding line would appear to trigger your code into a loop.

Comment: Yes I agree with that, but how can I make it so it avoids the first row. I thought maybe putting an ```If Not``` statement would allow me to keep the format for the first row

Comment: may be `if not(target.row=1) then ...`

Comment: @TheGridLock I tried that approach, it still seems to be clearing Row 1's interior coloring

Comment: add `application.enableevent = false` and true to the beginning and end of the code like screenupdateing or you should not use range.select in the code body

Comment: @TheGridLock I have update my code and explanation to make thing easier to understand, please let me know your suggestions

Comment: `With TR` With blocks allow clean bulk actions on an object. It doesn't make sense to have a `With` block with a boolean (Target.Row > 2). Not sure if you are looking for an `If/Else` construct there or were planning to act on Target or something else entirely.

Comment: For the highlighting function it doesn't matter what I use, as long as it highlight the active row and when selecting another active row, it clears the previous coloring and only colors the active row then that works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Not completely sure what you're doing, but this should clear the previous row if a cell in row 3 downwards is selected.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False                                                          'This speeds up the macro by hiding what the macro is doing

If Target.Row > 1 Then                                                         'Doesn't Allow the "Titles" in Row 1 to be highlighted or changed
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="MyRange", RefersToR1C1:=Range("A" & (Target.Row))   'Defines the name of the ActiveCell as "MyRange" to Autofill VLookup Formula on sheet
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Offset(1).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 0    
    Target.EntireRow.Interior.Color = RGB(243, 243, 123)                                                                             'With Target refers to the Active Row being selected                                             'Highlights the entire row that contain the active cell

    If Target.Address = "$A$2" Then                                                         'Checks if you have selected Row 2 (The comparison row)
        Target.Value = ""                                                                   'If Cell A2 is selected (the "Key" comparison cell from the comparison row) then a blank value is inputted
    Else
        [a2] = Target                                                                  'Makes cell "A2" equal to the Active Cell value (The "Key" in this case)
    End If

    Me.Range("B2:CK2").Interior.Color = xlNone                                              'Clears any previous (if any) colouring inside cells

    Dim rng As Range                                                                        'Declares variable as a range to store values

    For Each rng In Me.Range("D2:CK2")                                                      'Declares which columns to highlight yellow if there are any parameters in Sheet 2 that vary from Sheet 1
        If IsNumeric(rng.Value) And IsNumeric(Me.Cells(Target.Row, rng.Column)) Then        '[Exludes the Key, Date, Time & Part columns: hence starting at Column D for highlighting variances]
            If rng.Value <> Me.Cells(Target.Row, rng.Column).Value Then                     'Checks if the parameters vary from the main Database ("HE 171")
                rng.Interior.Color = vbYellow                                               'Highlights any varying parameters in Yellow
            End If
        End If
    Next
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True                                                           'Must be "True" after running the code to be able to Read/Write the Workbook

End Sub
```

Comment: I have edited my code to make it simpler for the thread's sake, the code always select column "A" of the active row when selecting any active cell excluding Row 1, and rename that Column A cell "My Range" Temporarily. That's what the first few lines achieve, afterwards I am trying to Highlight any active row after Row 2, and clear the highlight when another active row is selected. Currently when selecting another active row, the previous row is not clearing the coloring. I hope this clears up some things, please let me know

Comment: Yes I have, it seems to be clearing the coloring of the row above the active cell only (this is because of the ```offset``` property in the ``` If Target.Row > 2 Then Target.Offset(-1).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 0  ``` I tried to use your code simply without the ```offset(-1)``` but it doesn't seem to do the trick quite yet

Comment: Code amended above.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Works great, just replaced your ```[a2] = Target ``` with ```[a2] = ActiveCell``` other than that it does what I need it to

Comment: OK, I just forgot to clear the rest of the sheet of formatting. The activecell should be the same as Target.